# canvas getContext in Meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code displays a canvas on mobile phone screen for clients to draw a signature but the browser is reporting error

> TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

```
 Template.myName.events({
   'mousemove canvas.signature': function (event) {
    let canvas = $(event.target);  
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); //<-- ERROR  -----------------
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, 2, 2);
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="myName">
  <canvas class="signature"></canvas>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

canvas != canvas

If canvas = canvas, then canvas.getContext is a function.

Comment: OK, And how can I get the reference to the canvas element?